# df <- mpg, col_name <- hwy, how to call mpg$hwy? df[col_name] doesn't work

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to call  `filter(df, col_name == value)` such as `filter(mpg, hwy == 27)`, but

```
df <- mpg
col_name <- 'hwy'
value <- 27
col <- df[col_name]
filter(df, col == value)
```

yields the error

Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `col == value`.
x object 'value' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

How can I correct `col_name <- df[col_name]` so that it doesn't produce this error? I've noticed that typeof() and class() produce different results for col (list; tbl_df, tbl, data.frame) and mpg$df (int;int). How do I change col (an object of class tibble and type list) to the same type as mpg$df (int)?

---

`rlang::last_error()` gave:

<error/dplyr_error>
Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.

i Input `..1` is `.data[["hwy"]] == value`.

x Column `hwy` not found in `.data`

Backtrace:

Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

Comment: `df[[col_name]]` See [Difference between `[` and `[[`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)

Comment: df[[col_name]] is also not working for me

Comment: It works with me, the return value is a df with 14 rows and 11 columns.

Comment: I assume from the error message that you're using `dplyr::filter`, but it's good to note where all your non-base R functions come from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `.data`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df,  .data[[col_name]] == value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 x 11
   manufacturer model        displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class     
   <chr>        <chr>        <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>     
 1 audi         a4             3.1  2008     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact   
 2 audi         a4 quattro     2    2008     4 auto(s6)   4        19    27 p     compact   
 3 chevrolet    malibu         2.4  1999     4 auto(l4)   f        19    27 r     midsize   
 4 hyundai      sonata         2.4  1999     4 manual(m5) f        18    27 r     midsize   
 5 hyundai      tiburon        2    2008     4 auto(l4)   f        20    27 r     subcompact
 6 nissan       altima         2.4  1999     4 auto(l4)   f        19    27 r     compact   
 7 nissan       altima         3.5  2008     6 manual(m6) f        19    27 p     midsize   
 8 pontiac      grand prix     3.8  1999     6 auto(l4)   f        17    27 r     midsize   
 9 subaru       forester awd   2.5  2008     4 manual(m5) 4        20    27 r     suv       
10 subaru       impreza awd    2.5  2008     4 auto(s4)   4        20    27 r     compact   
11 subaru       impreza awd    2.5  2008     4 manual(m5) 4        20    27 r     compact   
12 toyota       camry          2.2  1999     4 auto(l4)   f        21    27 r     midsize   
13 toyota       camry solara   2.2  1999     4 auto(l4)   f        21    27 r     compact   
14 toyota       camry solara   3.3  2008     6 auto(s5)   f        18    27 r     compact
```

---

or convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`

```
filter(df,  !! rlang::sym(col_name) == value)
```

---

Note: Here we used

```
col_name <- "hwy"
```

Comment: Both of these methods produced the same error for me

Comment: @Mark Are you using `col_name <- "hwy"` or `col_name <- df[col_name]`.  I assumed that it is the first case

Comment: @Mark Please note that when you assign the same object to `df[col_name]` is now a data.frame with one column as opposed to the string you have first assigned

Comment: I used `col_name <- "hwy"`

Comment: @Mark Both of the soluitons I showed is working for me with `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.6’`

Comment: when I ran yours I forgot to stor value <-27 . its working. thanks